# Pygame: Collision With tiles not working

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently working on an abstraction layer for pygame, and have come across a problem when trying to check collisions with the maps. I am able to load and display the map, as well as store rectangles which are collidable. When I print the list of rectangles, I see that everything is in place, but when I iterate over every rect and try to check collision with another rect, it always returns true even when the rects do not collide. Also, when I try to debug all the rects by drawing a red-outlined rectangle over each one of them, nothing gets drawn even though when I print the rectangle, it prints a rectangle which exists.

Here are a few snippets from the framework:

```
class Tilemap(object):
"""This is the tilemap object, it takes an array of strings as its object, and places a surface where you have it in the strings. It only supports one surface per map, so you have to make multiple maps for floor, walls, etc."""
def __init__(self, level_surface,level_string = None, string_char = "#", surface = None, surface_dim = Vector2(50, 50),surface_color = (255, 255, 255)):
    self.level = level_string
    self.char = string_char
    self.surface = surface
    if self.surface is None:
        self.surface = pygame.Surface(surface_dim)
        self.surface.fill(surface_color)

    self.surface_width = self.surface.get_rect().w
    self.surface_height = self.surface.get_rect().h
    self.collision_list = []
    for y in xrange(len(self.level)):
        for x in xrange(len(self.level[y])):
            if self.level[y][x] is self.char:
                self.collision_list.insert(len(self.collision_list), Rect((x) * self.surface_width,(y) * self.surface_height, self.surface_width, self.surface_height))
    print self.collision_list
    for y in xrange(len(self.level)):
        for x in xrange(len(self.level[y])):
            if self.level[y][x] is self.char:
                level_surface.blit(self.surface.convert_alpha(), (self.surface_width * x, self.surface_height * y))

def replace_char_with(self, level_surface,char = ".", surface = None):
    for y in xrange(len(self.level)):
        for x in xrange(len(self.level[y])):
            if self.level[y][x] is char:
                level_surface.blit(surface.convert_alpha(), (surface.get_width() * x, surface.get_height() * y))

def check_col(self, rect):
    for tilerect in self.collision_list:
        if rect.x + rect.w > tilerect.x or rect.y + rect.h > tilerect.y or rect.x < tilerect.x + tilerect.w or rect.y < tilerect.y + tilerect.h:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def debug_draw(self, screen):
    for rect in self.collision_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), rect, 2)
```

Snippet # 2, The testing code:

```
def main():
from pygame.locals import K_w, K_a, K_s, K_d
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
player = Sprite(pygame.image.load("trapdoor_tile.png"), Vector2(100, 100))
floor = ["########################################",
         "########################################",
         "#####...##.#.#..###.#.###..#############",
         "#####.######.#.#.####.##.#.#############",
         "######.###.#.##..##.#.###.##############",
         "#####.####.########.####################",
         "#####.#.##.###.#.##.#.##.#.#############",
         "########################################",
         "#######################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################"
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################",
         "########################################"]

walls = ["########################################",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "#......................................#",
         "########################################"]

level_surf = pygame.Surface((640, 480))
floor_map = Tilemap(level_surf, floor, "#", pygame.image.load("ground_tile.png").convert_alpha())
floor_map.replace_char_with(level_surf, ".", pygame.image.load("trapdoor_tile.png").convert_alpha())
wall_map = Tilemap(level_surf, walls, "#", pygame.image.load("wall_tile.png").convert_alpha())

while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    milliseconds = clock.tick(60) / 10.

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.locals.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            raise SystemExit

    wall_map.debug_draw(screen);

    screen.blit(level_surf, Vector2(0, 0))

    if wall_map.check_col(player.dummyrect):
        player.colliding = True
        print "why!"
    else:
        player.colliding = False

    player.update(milliseconds)
    player.draw(screen)

    keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    player.apply_drag()

    if keystate[K_w]:
        player.set_accel_y(-5)
    elif keystate[K_s]:
        player.set_accel_y(5)
    elif keystate[K_a]:
        player.set_accel_x(-5)
    elif keystate[K_d]:
        player.set_accel_x(5)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

The sprite class from which the player is created:

```
class Sprite(object):
def __init__(self, surface = None, initial_position = (100, 100)):
    self.surface = surface
    self.rect = self.surface.get_rect(center = initial_position)
    self.acceleration = Vector2(0, 0)
    self.delta_time = None
    self.dummyrect = self.rect
    self.colliding = False

def update(self, delta_time):
    self.dummyrect = self.rect.move(self.acceleration.x * delta_time, self.acceleration.y * delta_time)
    if not self.colliding:
        self.rect = self.dummyrect
    else:
        self.dummyrect = self.rect
    self.delta_time = delta_time

def draw(self, screen):
    screen.blit(self.surface, self.rect)

def draw_to_cam(self, screen,camera):
    screen.blit(self.surface, camera.to_camera_coords(Vector2(self.rect.x, self.rect.y)))

def collide(self, rectangle):
    if self.rect.x + self.rect.w > rectangle.x:
        self.rect.x -= 1;
    if self.rect.x < rectangle.x + rectangle.w:
        self.rect.x += 1
    if self.rect.y < rectangle.y + rectangle.h:
        self.rect.y += 1;
    if self.rect.y + self.rect.h > rectangle.y:
        self.rect.y -= 1;

def set_accel_x(self, new_val):
    self.acceleration.x = new_val

def set_accel_y(self, new_val):
    self.acceleration.y = new_val

def apply_drag(self, drag_mul = 1):
    if self.acceleration.x > 0:
        self.acceleration.x -= self.delta_time * drag_mul
    else:
        self.acceleration.x += self.delta_time * drag_mul

    if self.acceleration.y > 0:
        self.acceleration.y -= self.delta_time * drag_mul
    else:
        self.acceleration.y += self.delta_time * drag_mul

    if self.acceleration.x < 0.1 or self.acceleration.x > -0.1:
        self.acceleration.x = 0
    if self.acceleration.x < 0.1 or self.acceleration.x > -0.1:
        self.acceleration.x = 0
    if self.acceleration.y < 0.1 or self.acceleration.y > -0.1:
        self.acceleration.y = 0
    if self.acceleration.y < 0.1 or self.acceleration.y > -0.1:
        self.acceleration.y = 0

def get_center(self):
    return Vector2(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery)
```

Those are the three main snippets involved, I have no idea why a collision is returned every time, but it seems to do so. If anyone has an answer, or explanation at least, as to why this occurs, please Help a brother out!

Comment: `class Sprite(object):` should be deriving from `pygame.sprite.Sprite` . Your collisions should be using either `Rect`'s collision functions, or `Sprite`'s collision functions, depending on if its rect on rect, or rect on sprite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check_col function is using all 'or' operators, meaning you're returning true for a collision as long as even just one condition is met.  Here is your code:

```
def check_col(self, rect):
for tilerect in self.collision_list:
    if rect.x + rect.w > tilerect.x or rect.y + rect.h > tilerect.y or rect.x < tilerect.x + tilerect.w or rect.y < tilerect.y + tilerect.h:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

What you want is something more like this:

```
def check_col(self, rect):
    for tilerect in self.collision_list:
        if ((rect.x + rect.w > tilerect.x and rect.x <= tilerect.x + tilerect.width) or
            (tilerect.x + tilerect.width > rect.x and tilerect.x <= rect.x + rect.width)) and
            ((rect.y + rect.h > tilerect.y and rect.y <= tilerect.y + tilerect.height) or
            (tilerect.y + tilerect.height > rect.y and tilerect.y <= rect.y + rect.height))

            return true
        else:
            return false
```

Also, it might be worth pointing out that pygame's Rect class has its own set of collision detection functions.  To detect a collision between 2 rects you can use rect.colliderect(Rect).

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect

Answer (score 1):

You need some `and`'s in your collision checking.

For Example:

```
def check_col(self, rect):
    for tilerect in self.collision_list:
        collide_x = False
        collide_y = False
        # check x axis for collision
        if self.rect.x + self.rect.w > tilerect.x:
            collide_x = True
        elif self.rect.x < tilerect.x + tilerect.w:
            collide_x = True
        # check y axis for collision
        if self.rect.y < tilerect.y + tilerect.h:
            collide_y = True
        elif self.rect.y + self.rect.h > tilerect.y:
            collide_y = True
        # act on a collision on both axis
        if collide_x and collide_y:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Are you testing two rectangles rect on point? for [1] http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect else http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint

Comment: @monkey I don't fully know what he wants with these rectangles (pretty sure its grid based in which case there are much better ways), so I just modified his code to work.

Comment: The function you changed was not his collision detection function, it's his collision reaction function.  The function doing the collision detection was check_col in the TileMap class.

Comment: @Haz you appear to be correct. Both functions are doing the same logic which has the same error however.